# Force a 404 page for certain URL parameters

Tags: .htaccess

How do I force a 404 error through htaccess for URLs that contain "mobile=no"?

This question is not the same as a previously answered question.   This one deals with returning a 404 for URLs that contain a certain parameter.  In my case, "mobile=no".

Comment: I just read that question and answer   My question is not a duplicate of that one.

Comment: I'm not sure if making your users to go to a mobile version of the site is a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^mobile=no$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ 404.html [R=404,L,NC]
```

Comment: I tried both the first and second answer.  Both seemed to work, but this answer gave me the ability to redirect to my custom 404 error page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?mobile=no [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]
```